# Clarification for WMS Service in MapServer

Tags: wms, mapserver

I am trying to understand the WMS service in MapServer. What I've done so far is making a complete map with a roads network some buildings and parks. Then I create an HTML template and by calling the url I get my map. My question is: is this map considered a WMS service?  This confuses me because I came across this http://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_server.html that explains how to set up a WMS server and so I set it up and now I can call fot the GetCapabilities and GetMap requests. So, this confuses me. Various resources on the internet refer to a simple map as a WMS. On the other hand, the link refers to the WMS as something a bit more different. Eventually what is the difference?

Comment: If you get a map with GetMap request and GetCapabilities work then it feels like WMS. If you fetch your map with mode=map or some other MapServer specific call then it is not WMS. It is possible to get both from the same mapfile, though.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I also create a caching service for a map I'm creating? For example this map I'm mentioning above is it helpful to cache it with mapcache for example ?

Comment: You can use MapCache for caching WMS sources as documented in http://www.mapserver.org/mapcache/config.html

Comment: Won't caching work in CGI mode? Is it only working in WMS service ?

Comment: Caching itself works but for MapCache (read the manual) "There are currently no sources other than WMS implemented, though others may be added later if the need arises". MapProxy probably can cache CGI directly, But activating WMS means only adding a few lines into the mapfile.

Comment: OK. So I've created the mapcache.xml. Restarting apache is giving me no errors. So everything is set up. How do I access my caching service? If I type  http://localhost/mapcache?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetCapabilities  I get an xml on the page. If I replace the GetCapabilites with GetMap I get "This site can’t be reached". How can I see my caching service?

Comment: If you get a valid response to GetCapabilities you have accessed your service. How did your GetMap look like?

Comment: The GetMap returns a static map of my image in which I have all layers set to default. So I see them all. What I'm trying to understand is that: MapCache comes with a "demo". When I access it I see tiles of the whole world caching, depending on the service (wms, wmts etc). So is this the case with MapCache? Am I supposed to see my map tiling too? And if yes, how do I access that? Thank you very much

Comment: Have you tried to use that service with some regular WMS client like QGIS? Am I right if I assume that you do not know WMS especially well yet?

Comment: If you mean this service:   http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/home/stefanos/mapdata/fifth.map&SERVICE=MWS&VERSION=1.3.1&REQUEST=GetMap  then yes I've tried it QGIS and it's working well. I'm adding each layer individually. (I've also set my mapfile to support WFS which is working well too in QGIS). And yes, you are right.... there's an "obscure cloud" in my head regarding the whole picture I have about WMS  :-(  All I know is GetMap returns png/jpeg and GetCapabilities an xml, both by a special protocol OGC

Comment: No, I meant the WMS service from the MapCache. Have you tried to read that service with QGIS from `http://localhost/mapcache?`

Comment: Yes, I just tried it. It's working. I open up the "Add WMS/WMTS Layer" button and on the "New" option I enter  http://localhost/mapcache?LAYERS=Roads&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.1  etc.   and I get my WMS service on the layer panel.   I still haven't figured out how to access it in the browser though.....

Comment: You need to read the documentation of your application library (OpenLayers, Leaflet...). You should have a working example installed with your MapCache, the same as this http://www.openbasiskaart.nl/mapcache/demo/tms and you can have a look at the source code of the page.

Comment: Yes. Demo is installed. Because I didn't know how to view, I retained the demo service and added my WMS service in the mapcache.xml too. So now to view my map I go to localhost/mapcache/demo and choose WMS (which I've set). So I'm seeing my map with openlayers. If I want to avoid the demo do I have to write the code my self? This code points OpenLayers version 2 if I'm right. I've set the cache to "disk" and switching to "sqlite" sometimes. In both situations my CPU is struggling to create the first tiles. My map is being pulled form PostGIS. Is it becase of that?

Comment: I am sorry but gis.stackexchange is not suitable forum for writing tutorials. You know now that you have a working WMS on your MapServer, as well as WMS on your MapCache, and a bunch of other services on your MapCache http://mapserver.org/mapcache/services.html.

Comment: Oh yeah... sorry... I extended this too much.  :-)  Thank you very much for your help so far   :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An OGC Web Map Service (WMS) is any **service** that conforms to the (well any version of the) OGC WMS standard.  The current version is [WMS 1.3.0](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=14416), though the previous version ([WMS 1.1.1](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=1081&version=1&format=pdf)) is also widely used.  Other versions exist but aren't commonly used.

At its simplest a service is deemed to be a WMS if supports two operations:

1. GetCapabilities
2. GetMap

Other operations exist such as:

- GetFeatureInfo

And when combined with the Styled Layer Descriptor (SLD) specification:

- GetLegendGraphic
- DescribeLayer
- GetStyles

A GetCapabilities is as you say an XML response to a request like:

http://myservice/ows?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities& ~ which should return the highest version of the WMS standard supported by your service

or a request like:

http://myservice/ows?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&version=1.1.1& ~ which should return a version 1.1.1 response for your service, if your service supports it...

The GetCapabilities response lets a client know all the operations supported by your service, the names of the layers, the coordinate reference system(s), and the extent, the link to metadata, feature data sets, and other datasets, the geographic extents of your layers, etc, etc.

A GetMap response is an image, it isn't just limited to gif/jpeg, the following image formats are supported in one MapServer service I know of... (as advertised in the GetCapabilities response)

```
<GetMap>
    <Format>image/png</Format>
    <Format>image/jpeg</Format>
    <Format>image/png; mode=8bit</Format>
    <Format>application/x-pdf</Format>
    <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
    <Format>image/tiff</Format>
    <Format>application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml</Format>
    <Format>application/vnd.google-earth.kmz</Format>
```